# Group by several columns with count on another column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, pivot

I'm using SQL SERVER 2012 and I'm struggling with this SQL statement. Basically I have this table

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTHok.png)

I want to group by Date, and Username, with a count on the status column, like below :

[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQZbo.png)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what is your dbms?

Comment: Please read the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an aggredated query with a few conditional `SUM`s.

```
SELECT 
    LastUpdate,
    UpdatedBy as User, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as A
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as C
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as D
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Z' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Z
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as X
FROM table
GROUP BY LastUpdate, UpdatedBy
ORDER BY LastUpdate, UpdatedBy
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Is there a way to tweak this though for group by date. Meaning, row 1 of query result is count of statuses for user 1 on the 12th. Row 2 is count of statuses for user2 on the 12th. Row 3 is count of statuses for user1 on the 13th etc..

Comment: @DelHabington, not sure that I understand what you mean... What are 12th rows, 13th rows and so on ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. When I say 12th and 13th, I'm referring to dates. So row 1 would be 12/12/2018, User1, and a count for all statuses. Row 2 would same date but for User2, and a count for all statuses. And repeat for each day. Look at the query result image I've uploaded to clarify

Comment: Ok @DelHabington, so you need an `ORDER BY` clause, by date then by user. I just updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using conditional aggregation

```
select LastUpdate,UpdatedBy, 
count(case when Status='A' then UpdatedBy end) as 'A',
count(case when Status='C' then UpdatedBy end) as 'C',
count(case when Status='D' then UpdatedBy end) as 'D',
count(case when Status='Z' then UpdatedBy end) as 'Z',
count(case when Status='X' then UpdatedBy end) as 'X'
from tablename
group by LastUpdate,UpdatedBy
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out with help from the guys answers

```
    SELECT 
    CAST(LastUpdate as DATE),
    UserName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Status_1],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Status_2],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Status_3]
FROM Table
WHERE LastUpdate BETWEEN '2018-11-30 10:013:44.080' AND '2018-12-30 10:013:44.080'
    GROUP BY CAST(LastUpdate as DATE), UserName
    ORDER BY CAST(LastUpdate as DATE)
```

This is a sample query where I'm looking for records between two dates. The problem I was having was in part due to filtering on datetime rather than date. The lastupdate column is a datetime so by casting to date it solved the issue

Comment: Make sure you upvote the answers that helped you figure it out